# Conditional foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have

```
class Item
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

and this code

```
public void(List<string> sd)        
{
    List<Item> newitems = new List<Item>();
    foreach(var item in sd)
    {
        newItems.Add(new Item { Id = item});
    }
}
```

If sd contains more than ten items I should create new object `List<Item>` and initialize it by values from 11 item.

How much better to do it?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to create multiple lists? i.e., you want to have `List<List<Item>>`?

Comment: If `sd` contains 21 items, do you need three lists?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to create lists of `Item` from a list of `string`, you can use `Select()` to create a list instead of `foreach`. Then, you just need to [split the list into sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq):

```
var allItems = sd.Select(id => new Item { Id = id });
var subLists = Split(allItems);
```

You can use the [`Split()` method in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419063/3165499):

```
public static List<List<object>> Split(List<object> source)
{
    return source
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 10)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a C++ programmer so forgive any bad syntax, but this is where you can use a reference to a `currentList` that varies as you create a new list each time one fills up, using an `if` condition within your `foreach`.

```
public void(List<string> sd)        
{
    // Create a list of lists to store your lists.
    List<List<Item>> lists;

    // We're going to use this variable to refer to our
    // current, not-yet-full list (less than 10 items).
    List<Item> currentList;

    // Create the first list you'll be adding items to,
    // and add it to our list of lists.
    currentList = new List<Item>();
    lists.Add(currentList);

    foreach(var item in sd)
    {
        currentList.Add(new Item { Id = item});

        if(currentList.Count() >= 10)
        {
            // This should look familiar from above :-)
            currentList = new List<Item>();
            lists.Add(currentList);
        }
    }
}
```

If I've got some syntax wrong, please feel free to edit and correct my answer.